# Sending a list of mails with SmtpClient

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I use SendCompletedEventHandler of SmtpClient when sending a list of emails.

The SendCompletedEventHandler  is only called when have already sent all emails in the list.

I expexted, that SendCompletedEventHandler   is called when an email is sent.

Is there something wrong in my code?

```
    public void SendAllNewsletters(List<string> recipients)
    {
        string mailText  = "My Text";
        foreach(string recipient in recipients)
        {
            //if this loop takes 10min then the first call to
            //SendCompletedCallback is after 10min
            SendNewsletter(mailText,recipient);
        }
    }

    public bool SendNewsletter(string mailText , string emailaddress)
    {

            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(_smtpServer, _smtpPort);
            System.Net.NetworkCredential SMTPUserInfo = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_smtpuser, _smtppassword);
            sc.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo;
            sc.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

            MailMessage mm = null;
            mm = new MailMessage(_senderemail, emailaddress );
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mm.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            mm.Subject = "Something";
            mm.Body = mailText ;
            mm.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            //Mail 
            string userState = emailaddress;
            sc.SendAsync(mm, userState);

            return true;
    }


    public void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the unique identifier for this asynchronous operation.
        String token = (string)e.UserState;
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            _news.SetNewsletterEmailsisSent(e.UserState.ToString(), _newslettername, false, e.Error.Message); 
        }
        else
        {
            _news.SetNewsletterEmailsisSent(e.UserState.ToString(), _newslettername, true, string.Empty);
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of `SmtpClient` each and every time (and then re-assigning the handler).  Use a static variable with a bigger scope.

Comment: It sounds like you're assuming that the handler can only be associated with one SmtpClient which isn't correct. Besides, he's creating a new handler each time so there is a 1:1 relationship.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected on my machine except that the constructor of MailMessage throw a format exception because `"My Tex"` is not a valid email address. The first argument is the email address of the sender.

As Josh Stodola points out, you should cache the `SmtpClient` for the life of this class rather than creating another one for each call. If you don't cache the `SmtpClient`, then you should add the following line to the end of your SendCompletedCallback (preferably in a finally block):

```
((SmtpClient)sender).SendCompleted -= SendCompletedCallback;
```

If this doesn't help you, perhaps you could post more details - such as what is the data in the event args that *do* get called?

Comment: Thnx, I updated the post to use the right syntax for MailMessage

Comment: Did it fix your problem though?